# installing 14.04.1 video lockup

Tags: 14.04

i installed 14.04.1 and i can sign on to my desktop but shortly after that is goes all funny screen get weird lines and locks up. i think the problem is my video card which is a NVIDIA GeForce 6150SE nforce 430 please help

Answer (score 0):

For me this card works only with nvidia driver version 173.14.39. (partialy, e.g. steam is unusable) So if you are using another proprietary driver, first remove it. 
If you are not able to do it in graphical mode, you can do it in recovery mode. When pc starts press shift key and grub menu should appear. Select recovery mode, first run fsck, and than go to root console and run:

```
apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
shutdown -r now
```

Pc should restart with opensource drivers loaded. Than go to settings and change drivers to nvidia 173.1.39.